# SQL query in Kibana

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I am currently querying an index where I would like to know  the count of emails with _ character in them in Kibana  ES

```
SELECT email FROM email_dexk WHERE email LIKE '/_/%';
```

Expected results:

```
abc_bg@we.com
sdbd_rf@ss.info
```

But the results I see are either 0 or a bad request

Appreciate if I could get the correct query.

Comment: try: `SELECT email FROM email_dexk WHERE email LIKE "_%";`

Comment: @Asdfg, SQL treats it as wildcard operator and results in all the results being displayed

Comment: thats what % means. you are querying and asking for all the records where `email` field contains _. are you getting records which don't have _ when you run the query?

Comment: @Asdfg, "_"  is also an wildcard, typically matches all the records. Yes, records without _ are also fetched

Comment: why don't you just escape the "_"? you can define yourself what you use as an escape character: SELECT email FROM email_dexk WHERE email LIKE "?_%" escape ?;